# Is there a fix for Jockey failing to download package indexes?

Tags: nvidia, compiz, appearance, effects, jockey

I'm running the latest version of the proprietary nVidia driver, and I haven't had any problems enabling Compiz effects until a few days ago after tweaking my theming. When I try to enable effects from the Appearance panel, I get this popup window:

[image]

And, after working for a few seconds it turns to this:

[image]

Launching Jockey from the command line or application menu, it doesn't recognize my proprietary drivers nor will it complete the package index download successfully. Output of jockey.log:

```
010-12-21 11:31:52,242 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 11:31:58,162 DEBUG: ... fail!
2010-12-21 11:32:15,345 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x7f13ea279050>
2010-12-21 11:32:15,346 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/modules.alias
2010-12-21 11:32:15,506 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/bcmwl
2010-12-21 11:32:15,513 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia
2010-12-21 11:32:15,571 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/fglrx-modules.alias.override
2010-12-21 11:32:15,579 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-173
2010-12-21 11:32:15,590 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-96
2010-12-21 11:32:15,593 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-current
2010-12-21 11:32:15,967 WARNING: _detect_handlers(): No package repositories available, skipping check
2010-12-21 11:56:02,015 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 11:56:05,044 DEBUG: ... fail!
2010-12-21 11:56:22,847 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x7f071d91e2d8>
2010-12-21 11:56:22,848 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/modules.alias
2010-12-21 11:56:22,999 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/bcmwl
2010-12-21 11:56:22,999 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia
2010-12-21 11:56:23,054 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/fglrx-modules.alias.override
2010-12-21 11:56:23,055 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-173
2010-12-21 11:56:23,057 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-96
2010-12-21 11:56:23,059 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-current
2010-12-21 11:56:23,402 WARNING: _detect_handlers(): No package repositories available, skipping check
2010-12-21 11:56:30,662 DEBUG: Shutting down
2010-12-21 12:33:34,267 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 12:33:39,794 DEBUG: ... fail!
2010-12-21 12:34:01,366 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x7f28ff9202d8>
2010-12-21 12:34:01,367 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/modules.alias
2010-12-21 12:34:01,544 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/bcmwl
2010-12-21 12:34:01,545 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia
2010-12-21 12:34:01,603 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/fglrx-modules.alias.override
2010-12-21 12:34:01,605 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-173
2010-12-21 12:34:01,607 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-96
2010-12-21 12:34:01,608 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-current
2010-12-21 12:34:01,960 WARNING: _detect_handlers(): No package repositories available, skipping check
2010-12-21 12:37:20,743 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 12:37:23,362 DEBUG: ... fail!
2010-12-21 12:37:23,367 DEBUG: Shutting down
2010-12-21 14:44:08,534 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 14:44:14,607 DEBUG: ... fail!
2010-12-21 15:56:17,036 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 15:56:21,282 DEBUG: ... fail!
2010-12-21 15:56:39,950 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x1cc72d8>
2010-12-21 15:56:39,952 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/modules.alias
2010-12-21 15:56:40,154 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/bcmwl
2010-12-21 15:56:40,154 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia
2010-12-21 15:56:40,213 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/fglrx-modules.alias.override
2010-12-21 15:56:40,214 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-173
2010-12-21 15:56:40,217 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-96
2010-12-21 15:56:40,219 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-current
2010-12-21 15:56:40,619 WARNING: _detect_handlers(): No package repositories available, skipping check
2010-12-21 18:44:24,984 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 18:44:31,786 DEBUG: ... fail!
2010-12-21 18:44:49,601 DEBUG: updating <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x1da73b0>
2010-12-21 18:44:49,603 DEBUG: reading modalias file /lib/modules/2.6.35-22-generic/modules.alias
2010-12-21 18:44:49,864 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/bcmwl
2010-12-21 18:44:49,866 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/disable-upstream-nvidia
2010-12-21 18:44:49,917 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/fglrx-modules.alias.override
2010-12-21 18:44:49,919 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-173
2010-12-21 18:44:49,922 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-96
2010-12-21 18:44:49,923 DEBUG: reading modalias file /usr/share/jockey/modaliases/nvidia-current
2010-12-21 18:44:50,224 WARNING: _detect_handlers(): No package repositories available, skipping check
2010-12-21 18:46:19,366 DEBUG: Updating repository indexes...
2010-12-21 18:46:24,865 DEBUG: ... fail!
```

Does anyone know of a way to fix this? I miss my effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using the US update server rather than the main server; I switched it back under Software Sources and voila! 166 updates and Jockey doesn't gripe anymore.

Comment: having the same problem....solution doesn't worked for me.